# Trying to upgrade to patch CVE 2016-2017 and getting dependency errors

Tags: openssl

I am a attempting to upgrade and patch for CVE 2016-2017 and in doing so, I am receiving a error about dependencies. I've tried to resolve them, but I am a bit of a novice and when I attempt to fix the dependency issue, I get additional dependencies. I'm trying to do this based on several guides I've read.

If I run

```
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade libssl1.0.0 openssl
```

I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
openssl is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 grub-pc : Depends: grub2-common (= 1.99-21ubuntu3.18)
           Depends: grub-pc-bin (= 1.99-21ubuntu3.18)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I'm hoping someone can assist with what I need to do to resolve this.

Thanks!

**UPDATE 1** - I have run apt-get -f install and receive the following

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libjson-c2
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  grub-pc
The following packages will be upgraded:
  grub-pc
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 100 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/140 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-pc:
 grub-pc depends on grub2-common (= 1.99-21ubuntu3.18); however:
  Version of grub2-common on system is 1.99-21ubuntu3.20.
 grub-pc depends on grub-pc-bin (= 1.99-21ubuntu3.18); however:
  Version of grub-pc-bin on system is 1.99-21ubuntu3.20.
dpkg: error processing grub-pc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-pc
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**UPDATE 2** I've also run **sudo apt-get update**

```
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise Release.gpg
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-updates Release.gpg                                                                                               
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-backports Release.gpg                                                                                             
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-security Release.gpg                                                                                              
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise Release                                                                                                           
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-updates Release                                                                                                   
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-backports Release                                                                                                 
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-security Release                                                                                                  
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise/main Sources                                                                                                      
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise/restricted Sources                                                                                                
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise/universe Sources                                                                                                  
Get:1 http://stable.packages.cloudmonitoring.rackspace.com cloudmonitoring Release.gpg [490 B]                                                            
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise/multiverse Sources                                                                                                
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise/main amd64 Packages                                                                                               
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise/restricted amd64 Packages                                                                                         
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise/universe amd64 Packages                                                                                           
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise/multiverse amd64 Packages                                                                                         
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise/main i386 Packages                                                                                                
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise/restricted i386 Packages                                                                                          
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise/universe i386 Packages                                                                                            
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages                                                                                          
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise/main TranslationIndex                                                                                             
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex                                                                                       
Hit http://stable.packages.cloudmonitoring.rackspace.com cloudmonitoring Release                                                                          
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex                                                                                       
Ign http://stable.packages.cloudmonitoring.rackspace.com cloudmonitoring Release                                                                          
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise/universe TranslationIndex                                                                                         
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-updates/main Sources                                                                                              
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-updates/restricted Sources                                                                                        
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-updates/universe Sources                                                                                          
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-updates/multiverse Sources                                                                                        
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-updates/main amd64 Packages                                                                                       
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-updates/restricted amd64 Packages                                                                                 
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-updates/universe amd64 Packages                                                                                   
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages                                                                                 
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages                                                                                        
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages                                                                                  
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages                                                                                    
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages                                                                                  
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex                                                                                     
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex                                                                               
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise Release.gpg                                                                                                      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                                                                                                          
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg [198 B]                                                               
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex                                                         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                                                                                                         
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex                                                                                 
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-backports/main Sources                                                                                            
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-backports/restricted Sources                                                                                      
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-backports/universe Sources                                                                                        
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-backports/multiverse Sources                                                                                      
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-backports/main amd64 Packages                                                                                     
Ign http://stable.packages.cloudmonitoring.rackspace.com cloudmonitoring/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex                                                    
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-backports/restricted amd64 Packages                                                                               
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-backports/universe amd64 Packages                                                                                 
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages                                                                               
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-backports/main i386 Packages                                                                                      
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-backports/restricted i386 Packages                                                                                
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-backports/universe i386 Packages                                                                                  
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-backports/multiverse i386 Packages                                                                                
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-backports/main TranslationIndex                                                                                   
Ign http://stable.packages.cloudmonitoring.rackspace.com cloudmonitoring/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex                                                     
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex                                                                             
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-backports/restricted TranslationIndex                                                                             
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-backports/universe TranslationIndex                                                                               
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-security/main Sources                                                                                             
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise Release                                                                                                          
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-security/restricted Sources                                                                                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                                                                                              
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release [55.5 kB]                                                                                       
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg [198 B]                                                                                       
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-security/universe Sources                                                                                         
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-security/multiverse Sources                                                                                       
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-security/main amd64 Packages                                                                                      
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-security/restricted amd64 Packages                                                                                
Ign http://stable.packages.cloudmonitoring.rackspace.com cloudmonitoring/main TranslationIndex                                                            
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-security/universe amd64 Packages                                                                                  
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-security/multiverse amd64 Packages                                                                                
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-security/main i386 Packages                                                                                       
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages                                                                                 
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages                                                                                   
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages                                                                                 
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex                                                                                    
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex                                                                              
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex                                                                              
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex                                                                                
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise/main Translation-en                                                                                               
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise/multiverse Translation-en                                                                                         
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise/restricted Translation-en                                                                                         
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise/universe Translation-en                                                                                           
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-updates/main Translation-en                                                                                       
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en                                                                                 
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en                                                                                 
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en                                                                                   
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-backports/main Translation-en                                                                                     
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner amd64 Packages                                                                                           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release                                                                                                             
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en                                                                               
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-en                                                                               
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en                                                                                 
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-security/main Translation-en                                                                                      
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en                                                                                
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en                                                                                
Hit http://mirror.rackspace.com precise-security/universe Translation-en                                                                                  
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner i386 Packages                                                                                            
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release [55.4 kB]                                                                      
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner TranslationIndex                                                      
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [3,363 B]                                  
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                                                                                                
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en                                                                               
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages [3,542 B]                                                          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse amd64 Packages                                                                                           
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex                                     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages                                                  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en                                       
Hit http://stable.packages.cloudmonitoring.rackspace.com cloudmonitoring/main amd64 Packages                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex                         
Hit http://stable.packages.cloudmonitoring.rackspace.com cloudmonitoring/main i386 Packages
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [17.1 kB]      
Ign http://stable.packages.cloudmonitoring.rackspace.com cloudmonitoring/main Translation-en_US                 
Ign http://stable.packages.cloudmonitoring.rackspace.com cloudmonitoring/main Translation-en
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [17.3 kB]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
Fetched 153 kB in 4s (36.0 kB/s)              
W: GPG error: http://stable.packages.cloudmonitoring.rackspace.com cloudmonitoring Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A086F077D05AB914
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

**FINAL UPDATE**

With help from @db429 I was able to get to the root of my issue. I had some bad PPAs that I needed to remove. Once that was done, I had to remove grub-pc, then update, then re-install grub.

At that point, I was able to get everything going as expected.

Comment: the answer is already in your post  `You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' `. in the ubuntu case it should be `sudo apt -get install -f`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, db429. I should have included that I've also done that, which still returns a grub-related error.

I've updated the original post.

Comment: That is a grub2 (grub-pc) error and unrelated to your CVE / ssl question. Either wait for an update to the package or file a bug report so the maintainers can resolve the dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, bodhi.zazen - Sorry, I am a bit of a novice here. Does that mean that there is no way for me to resolve the CVE-2016-2017 issue?

Comment: you have the most cureent open-ssl. why are  you not updating your system? 100 updates is quit a lot.  try `sudo apt-get update` then remove the packagees `sudo apt-get remove grub-pc-bin grub2-common grub-common` afterwards reinstall it with `sudo apt install grub-common grub-gfxpayload-lists grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common` and then update your system with `sudo apt-get ugrade`

Comment: @db429 I think I'm getting farther down the rabbit hole here. I've updated the original post - but it looks like I'm getting 404's on {apt-get update}

Sadly, this is a server that I recently inherited, and I am a bit of a novice - I've never dealt with something that gave me so many issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay thats quite a construction site you inherited.

So far we have 4 issues to solve: the unmet grub dependencies, a non existent ppa in your sources.list, missing gpg-key for the rackspace repository and 100 updates waiting.

- First of. The 404 from running `sudo apt-get update` is due to that repository is not existent any more. More on repositories you can find [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine). Therefore we will have to comment it out in the source lists. Open the respective file `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` - you can also use vim.  Find the three lines starting with `http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5/...` and add `#` in front of it - save the file. Perhaps it is a file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ - not sure about that, it's 4 years ago I used 12.04 - the procedure stays the same.
- Now let's add the current ppa by the same programmer with `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php` (if your system is running php5.4 use `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable`- see [here](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php)). This will update the repositories after adding the gpg-key and the repository - if there appears an `W: GPG error:` let's ignore it for a moment.
- Before we can upgrade the 100 others, we first have to fix the grub issue - therefore we will go uninstall `sudo apt-get remove grub-common` and reinstall them `sudo apt-get install grub-pc` - difference in packages is due to dependencies; all grub packages depend on grub-common, while grub-pc pulls them all back in.
- If so far we didn't encounter any new problems, let's go and update all these 100 packages. Let's go to work with `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, we use dist-upgrade instead of upgrade, because it is more clever ;) - see [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/apt-get.8.html). It might be necessary to do this several times.
- For the pgp-key of the http://stable.packages.cloudmonitoring.rackspace.com repository it might be best to contact them, as I did not find their key anywhere on the standard keyservers. the procedure to make your system recognize the key can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Authentication_Tab) - until then a `sudo apt-get upgrade --allow-unauthenticated` might solve this last bastion.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed breakdown. I was fortunately able to figure it all out, (once you got me looking in the correct direction) and before your reply. But, these are the steps I ended up taking. I am happy to report that I now have the proper patch and those 100 updates have been fixed. Thanks again!

Comment: no problem, just saw that you edited your question after I had posted the answer - thx though for still accepting it.